# finding sum of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I need some hint to find the sum of the series. 
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n3^n}$$
I calculated using mathematica. it gives the sum as $\log(3/2)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the expansion

$$-\log{(1-x)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} $$

Then you should get

$$-\log{\frac{2}{3}} = \log{3}-\log{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n 3^n}$$

Comment: Are there any other way to find the sum without using power series expansion?

Comment: Well, you could take a derivative to obtain a geometrical sum, then integrate.