# Find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n6^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n6^n}$

1. I tried to apply the method of undetermined coefficients. But I didn't understand exactly how to apply it for $\frac{1}{6^n}$
2. I thought that here you can somehow apply the formula for the sum of an infinitely decreasing geometric progression, but I do not know what to do with a variable coefficient $q = \frac{1}{6n}$

It seems to me that it can be somehow reduced to ln, but I have not figured out how

Comment: Sorry, [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655243/sum-the-series-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac12n-n?noredirect=1) might be better. It also works for $6^n$ instead of $2^n$. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792986/finding-sum-of-a-series?noredirect=1).